# Genetic Algorithm for Data modem for GSM voice channel

Tags: signals, signal-processing, genetic-algorithm, gsm, genetic-programming

I'm working on a project of data modem for a GSM voice channel. I'm coding with C++

The main idea of modem: generate speech-like symbols, code data in it and send throught GSM codec.
The GA is used to generate these symbols.

The main idea of GA is:

1. Generate initial symbol set
2. Generate random data
3. Code data into symbols
4. Send it through gsm codec
5. Recieve the data from codec
6. Decode it into original data from point 2
7. Calculate the percentage of rubbish data

Then there is cycle until one of the following conditions is met:
all iterations has been passed or rubbish data percentage is low enough.

I was able to implement the algorithm, but GA opeators - crossover and mutation - does not work properly. it turns so, that the initial set is the best one and the others are worse.

In my algorithm I use ranking selection with probability distribution с*(1-с)^n
n - number of element in a rank
c - a GA parameter. In article they put it 0.075.

The crossover:
G' = b*G1 + (1-b)*G2
b is from [-a, 1+a]. a=0.5
G' - the complex spectra of an offspring
G1, G2 - complex spectras of parents.
Parents are selected with roulette wheel rotation according to ranking selection.

Mutation:

1. Randomnly select a symbol
2. Choose a random complex number from [-1; 1]x[-1; 1]
3. Substitute one of his 1..Nf components in complex spectra. The number of component is also chosen randomnly

The probability of mutation is 0.1.
The probability of crossover is 0.9.

I also use the elitism, which means that I put the best symbols from the previous generation to the next.

Nonetheless, it is useless. Crossover and mutation doestn't work properly.

Maybe somebody has been working in this project already or on similiar ones?
I also give a link for a full article:
[Here is the article](http://v3solar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/LaDueIEEEpaper.pdf)
The algorithm is decribed at section 4.
**UPD**: full source code
[source code](https://yadi.sk/d/DjZru18bk3BFp)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
void Alphabet::BlendCrossover(int offsprings)
{
int parentIndexes[2] = {-1, -1};
int copyIndex = 0;
float parameter;
float r = 0.0f;
float c = 0;
ComplexNumber ** childSpectra = new ComplexNumber*[N_SAMPLES];
ComplexNumber ** firstParentSpectra;
ComplexNumber ** secondParentSpectra;
Symbol * tmp;

SortByFitness();
DistributeProbabilities();
for(int i=0; i<N_SAMPLES;i++)
    childSpectra[i] = new ComplexNumber(0, 0);
for(int i=0; i<N_SYMBOLS - offsprings; i++)
    *(nextGeneration[i]) = *(symbolPool[i]);
for(int i=0; i<offsprings; i++)
{
    do
    {
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            r = GenerateRandomNum((float)0.0, (float)1.0);
            c = 0.0;
            for(int k=0; k<N_SYMBOLS; k++)
            {
                c += symbolPool[k]->GetProbability();
                if(r < c)
                {
                    parentIndexes[j] = k;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while(parentIndexes[0] == -1 || parentIndexes[1] == -1 || parentIndexes[0] == parentIndexes[1]);
    firstParentSpectra = symbolPool[parentIndexes[0]]->GetSpectra();
    secondParentSpectra = symbolPool[parentIndexes[1]]->GetSpectra();
    parameter = GenerateRandomNum((float)-0.5, (float)1.5);
    for(int j=0; j<N_SAMPLES; j++)
    {
        childSpectra[j]->SetRealPart(secondParentSpectra[j]->GetRealPart() + parameter*(firstParentSpectra[j]->GetRealPart() -
            secondParentSpectra[j]->GetRealPart()));
        childSpectra[j]->SetImPart(secondParentSpectra[j]->GetImPart() + parameter*(firstParentSpectra[j]->GetImPart() - 
            secondParentSpectra[j]->GetImPart()));
    }
    InverseDFT(childSpectra, nextGeneration[N_SYMBOLS - 1 - i]);
    nextGeneration[N_SYMBOLS - 1 - i]->timesCoded = 0;
    nextGeneration[N_SYMBOLS - 1 - i]->timesDecoded = 0;
}
for(int i = 0; i<N_SYMBOLS; i++)
    *(symbolPool[i]) = *(nextGeneration[i]);

}

void Alphabet::Mutate(int offsprings)
{
int randomIndex = (int)GenerateRandomNum(N_SYMBOLS - 1 - offsprings, N_SYMBOLS-1);
int randomComponent = (int)GenerateRandomNum(1, N_FREQUENCIES);
ComplexNumber ** spectra = symbolPool[randomIndex]->GetSpectra();

spectra[randomComponent]->SetRealPart((float)GenerateRandomNum((float)-1.0, (float)1.0));
spectra[randomComponent]->SetImPart((float)GenerateRandomNum((float)-1.0, (float)1.0));
InverseDFT(spectra, symbolPool[randomIndex]);
symbolPool[randomIndex]->Normalize();
symbolPool[randomIndex]->timesCoded = 0;
symbolPool[randomIndex]->timesDecoded = 0;
return;
}
```

Comment: It's weird that the initial population is the best one, and even if your operators are wrongly implemented I would say that even by chance that shouldn't happen often. Are you sure about the rest of the implementation? Did you roll your own GA code? Can you share the entire code? If you can't share it, my suggestion is to start by using an existing library and try to encode your problem using the standard operators.

Comment: @AkiRoss Added the entire code. I was able to determine the problem: for some reason crossover produces new offspring, which is rather similiar to some individuals from previus iterations. And I need the euclidian distance between all my individuals in alphabet to be as much as possible.

Comment: Given that I know nothing about GSM and signal processing, I find your GA code a bit weird (beside you commenting out crossover and mutation prob) 1. it looks you you select the offspring INSIDE the crossover. It should be outside, then you crossover and mutate them. 2. crossover and mutation probability are used per individual-pair (crossover) and per single (mutation) individual, not to the entire population. In general, the structure of your code is tightly coupled with the GA implementation and this doesn't help my reading, but this is related with software engineering and not code itself.

Comment: @Alex is there any progress in your project data modem for a GSM voice channel?
And Source code link doesn't work.